# DB2 on Cloud: ON CONFLICT REPLACE

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I am trying to add **ON CONFLICT REPLACE** constrain in IBM bluemix DB2 (on Cloud) table

```
CREATE TABLE DEVICE_TABLE (
    DEVICE_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    DEVICE_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    DEVICE_MAC VARCHAR(255),
    UNIQUE (PANEL_DEVICE_ID) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
}
```

but on create it is giving error

```
"CONFLICT" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.22.36
```

Same table is working for SQLITE3 but not with DB2 not sure what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This doc https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html says

> ON CONFLICT ... is a non-standard clause ... it is not part of standard SQL

So it is maybe not unexpected that Db2 does not support this non-standard clause. In general, although SQL does have an ISO standard, as Wikipedia says https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

> Despite the existence of such standards, most SQL code is not completely portable among different database systems without adjustments

If you need to "replace" a row if a row already exists with the same key value, you would likely want to use a `MERGE` statement rather than an INSERT in Db2. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html

Comment: Thanks Vernon, I am using Node-Red, db2 output node to insert data in my table and dont find MERGE option there

Comment: I don't know Node-Red, but I guess you would need to delete in the target table (or exclude from the insert) any rows that already exist, if it does not support MERGE